# Swift: Schedule a Event(Not Notification) for a specific time on weekdays

Tags: iphone, swift, events, background-process, background-service

Schedule a Event for a specific time on weekdays

That Event Wakeup My Application and have Share my Current Latitude longitude in my server through service call.

So Which iOS feature i have used to satisfy my Requirement.

Why i m not used LocalNotification Because LocalNotification insert Notification in Notification Bar And I Don't Set LocalNotification.

Comment: Can I Used EKAlaram Class? and this class is wake up my application when its firer.

Comment: i found  Background Modes Available in ios but which mode i have use for this Requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use local notifications with following code which will act like silent notifications and will not add notification into notification bar.

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeZone* timezone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
notification.timeZone = timezone;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

Remember you have to implement following method in appDelegate.m

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification{
```

Comment: Can i set Notification setting in appDelegate file.

Comment: @nalawala What do you mean by notifications setting? You can set notification send permission in appDelegate file. and also you can set notifications depending on functions.

Comment: yes notification not insert in notification canter. but when i schedule date after 2 min i m not recive notificat at  didReceiveLocalNotification method

Comment: example my Current time is 2016-05-25 13:26:00 +0000 and i have set fire date after 1 minute so date is 2016-05-25 13:27:00 +0000.but notification is not fire.